# Is there any way to use an ac load ssr with a dc load

Tags: microcontroller, ac, dc, solid-state-relay

i have a s202s01 relay that i want to connect to my microcontroller. The problem is that the load i want to control is a DC source. Is there any way to make that ssr (3-24dc, 8A 250VAC) work with a 12v 0.5A DC load?

I haven't tried anything yet because i don't want to damage it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose something suitable for DC.

Your relay has a Triac output. The problem is that in order for a Triac to turn off, the current must drop to near zero. For AC, that would happen every half-cycle; but for DC that would likely require turning off the DC supply.

12V @ 0.5A is a pretty simple requirement. For a low-side switch, an N-channel MOSFET would work nicely, although if your load is inductive, you will also need a flyback diode.

Comment: I could turn the dc source off for a moment and start it again with a second ssr. That would work without any damage?

Comment: That sounds silly to me. It would be a pain. You could probably do that, but then why not choose an SSR designed for DC? The right tool for the right job.

Comment: Because of the cost, i already have the AC ssr, and at the local electronic store it costs me 20+ euros one ssr for DC. I know is not the best way to do it, but is the cheapest. And is not about turning on and off the DC source, is changing between 2 voltages that that source provides.

Comment: "I could turn the dc source off for a moment and start it again with a second ssr" ... So long as the second SSR is connected to the AC input of a 12VDC supply. If it is connected to DC such as with a battery, you still have the same problem of turning it off.

Comment: About the N-Channel MOSFET, it would work with a 3.3v on the gate at full capacity?

Comment: The second SSR would be connected before the AC to DC change would happen, so i think would work.

Comment: Make sure you choose an N-Channel MOSFET that is designed for logic levels. It needs a low enough Vgs(on) rating for your 3.3V

Comment: What Vgs(on) should I search for?I never worked with a N channel MOSFET

Comment: I'm reading some datasheets and i don't find any vgs(on). Could be the vgs(max)?

Comment: This has gotten beyond the scope of your original question. Look for "logic-level MOSFET", try searching here as there are many answers that cover this. I'm sorry, but I'm at work and don't have time for a proper answer to this additional question. It is not Vgs(max). Unfortunatly Vgs(on) is not a simple constant.